# One to many instance join in infomatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a two source table in mapping
Table 1:

```
   Taxid  sal_cd 
   1000.  A01
   1000.  B01
   2000.  C01
   3000.  D01
   4000.   Null
```

Table 2:

```
    OrderCode amt  sal_cd
     201.     20.   A01
     202.     30.   B01
     202.     10.   C01
     203.      5.   D01
```

Final data i want like below:
Target

```
Taxis. Ordercode. Amt
1000.   201.       20
1000.   202.       30
1000.   203.        0
2000.   201.        0
2000.   202.        10
2000.   202.        0
3000.   201.        0
3000.   202.        0
3000.   203.        5
4000.   201.        0
4000.   202.        0
4000.    203.       0
```

I tried in full outer join ... Its not helping

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly you need? Your result doesnt seems to be cross join. It doesnt seems to be  a full outer join on `sal_cd`. What is the logic to join those 2 tables?

Comment: Yeah... Is there a logic behind it? Please explain the criteria, 'caues as Koushik mentioned, it's not obvious.